# gdb set inferior-tty warning: GDB: Failed to set controlling terminal: Operation not permitted

Tags: linux, terminal, gdb, gnu, tty

I am trying to debug a program using (gdb) , this program has a command that let you route the Input/Output of the program been debug into other spawned terminal of the same system (`set inferior-tty <myTty>` ).
I open a new Terminal (`/dev/pts/22`) and set this option. And start debugging the program.

Straight after I get this message in the second terminal `GDB: Failed to set controlling terminal: Operation not permitted`

The Input/Output seems to be redirected to this Second Terminal but it missbehaves ending up the command not achieving its functionality.

Terminal1: https://asciinema.org/a/obOQEjLR7lGxLdcje1VQvEHiL
Terminal2: https://asciinema.org/a/AEjCyQFqSdiqXNBSRrVW2uuMa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second terminal, run something like:

```
tty && tail -f /dev/null
```

then use the output of the tty command with GDB just as you are currently doing.

Without the `tail` command your existing shell and GDB are both fighting for control of the terminal.

Comment: Thank you , it looks like it works , it grabs the standard input of that terminal.
It is though unable to pipe the stdout that should be printed there

Comment: Oh, it works with `tail` as well? I've always used `sleep INF`.

Comment: I use `sleep 99999`. Nice to know that `INF` works, if I ever have an especially long debugging session.